# If $A\ge0$, $A$ has a positive eigenvector, $D = diag(x_1, . . . , x_n).$ $ \Rightarrow $ $\rho {(A)^{ - 1}}({D^{ - 1}}AD)$ is stochastic

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ and

- $A$ is nonzero, and $A\ge0$,(i.e; all $a_{ij}\ge0$).
- $A$ has a positive eigenvector $x =[x_i]$.
- $D = diag(x_1, . . . , x_n).$
- $\rho (A) = \max \{ \left| \lambda  \right|:\lambda $ is eigenvalue of $A$   $\}$)

Why does $\rho {(A)^{ - 1}}({D^{ - 1}}AD)$ is stochastic matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Letting $1$ as the vector of all $1$'s, note that, $$D^{-1} A D 1=D^{-1} Ax=\lambda D^{-1} x=\lambda 1$$ Since $A$ is a nonnegative matrix, by [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), it follows that $\rho(A)>0$ and there is an eigenvector $x$ corresponding to $\rho(A)$ which is also positive. Then, taking $\lambda=\rho(A)$, you get the conclusion.

Comment: If $A\ge0 $ by Perron–Frobenius theorem $\rho (A) \ge 0$, no problem?

Comment: The Perron-Frobenius theorem doesn't do all you claim.  How do we account for a situation like $A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$? We need to, at some point, use the existence of a positive eigenvector.

Comment: @user1551 you are correct. I need to show that the matrix $A$ is primitive, hence $\rho(A)>0$ and I need to show that the positive eigenvector $x$ should necessarily correspond to $\rho(A)$. I will try to find a way to prove/expand these points.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I will try to show that the matrix is primitive so that I can apply Perron-Frobenius correctly.

Comment: @user1551, ok, I will think about it.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** Let $B=\frac1{\rho(A)}D^{-1}AD$. Suppose $x$ corresponds to some eigenvalue $\lambda<\rho(A)$. What are the limits of $\mathbf1^TB^m\mathbf1$, of $B^m$ and of $\rho(B)^m$ as $m\to\infty$?

*Remark.* The statement in the OP usually appears in textbooks in the following (equivalent) form, which I think is easier to understand:

> If $A\ge0,\ x>0$ and $Ax=\lambda x$, then $\lambda=\rho(A)$.

In other words, if $A\ge0$, no other eigenvalues than $\rho(A)$ can possibly give a positive eigenvector. (Whether $\rho(A)$ can actually give a positive eigenvector is case-dependent; Perron-Frobenius theorem only guarantees the existence of a nonnegative Perron vector when $A$ is only known to be nonnegative.)

Comment: $\rho {(B)^m} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{m \to \infty } \frac{1}{{\rho {{(A)}^m}}}{\left\| {{D^{ - 1}}{A^m}D} \right\|_2}$ .I dont understand next part. please complete your proof.

Comment: @H.S Have you evaluated $\lim_{m\to\infty}B^m$ first?

Comment: $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{m \to \infty } {B^m} = 0$, and next?? What is your intended purpose of "limits of $\mathbf1^TB^m\mathbf1$, of $B^m$ and of $\rho(B)^m$ as $m\to\infty$?"

Comment: @H.S Basically $\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbf1^TB^m\mathbf1=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{m\to\infty}B^m=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{m\to\infty}\rho(B)^m=0$, where the second implication is due to the fact that $\rho(B^m)=\rho(B)^m$.

Comment: Thanks for guide,  finally,  why is $B$ stochastic matrix?

Comment: @H.S You need to prove that $\rho(B)>0$. Therefore the implication that $\lim_{m\to\infty}\rho(B)^m=0$ (inferred from the assumption that $\lambda<\rho(A)$ is a contradiction. In other words, $\lambda$ must be equal to $\rho(A)$. Hence $B\mathbf1=\mathbf1$, i.e. $B$ is stochastic.