# $\rho(A)^{-1}D^{-1}AD$ a stochastic matrix with $A > 0 \in M_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Nonnegative Matrix Theory Experts,

Can we prove that $\rho(A)^{-1}D^{-1}AD$ is a stochastic matrix?

- $A > 0 \in M_n$ is a non-negative non-zero matrix that has a positive eigenvector say $x = [x_1,\cdots,x_n]$,
- $D = \textrm{diag}\left(x_1,\cdots,x_n\right)$ is a diagonal matrix comprising the elements of the eigenvector $x$ of $A$,
- and $\rho(A)$ is a spectral radius of $A$.

Thank you so much in advance,

Comment: It is not clear what exactly D is.

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: $D = \textrm{diag}\left(x_1,\cdots,x_n\right)$ is a diagonal matrix, where $\left\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\right\}$ corresponds to the respective eigenvectors of $A$. Does this explain?

Comment: Why is it diagonal? The matrix of eigenvectors of $A$ is almost never going to be diagonal.

Comment: I meant stacking the elements of an eigenvector $x = [x_1, \cdots, x_n]$ in a diagonal matrix $D$. That's the definition of the problem in hand.

Answer (score 0):

It's a duplicate: there is a same question with some answers herein [If $A\ge0$, $A$ has a positive eigenvector, $D = diag(x_1, . . . , x_n).$ $ \Rightarrow $ $\rho {(A)^{ - 1}}({D^{ - 1}}AD)$ is stochastic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592563/if-a-ge0-a-has-a-positive-eigenvector-d-diagx-1-x-n-rig?rq=1)